# How to show validation errors in rails via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you show the following errors that fail Rails validation using AJAX?

[image]

I have the following code in controller

```
      flash[:notice] = 'Please correct the errors below and try again.'
            format.html { render :action => :new }
            format.js 
      end
```

Added to view

```
 :remote => true
```

And then in create.js.erb I check the flash, but how do I show Rails errors that are shown when not using AJAX? or do I have to write validations from scratch here?

```
 <% if flash.present? %>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: You need to check jQuery validation plugin, or checkout its gem version - https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check model_name.errors?

otherwise you can create a empty div. Fill that div from ajax with the proper message regarding the error.

In create.js.erb

('#error').html("error")

In View